# How to create object that can be added to a List<T> array?

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a JSONMessage class that can parse a json string and add the objects contained in the message to the `List<T> t`.

The object contained in the message implements the interface JSONSerialisation and implements the two methods toJSON() and fromJSON().

The code below does not work because I cannot instantiate the Type T and I get an error on the row `t2.fromJSON...` (as t2 has not been initialized).

I am not sure if my approach here is correct and if what I try to is achievable (create a generic JSONMessage) that I can use to encode/parse different type of objects. If that approach is not possible, I would appreciate hints of how I could achieve a similar result.

Regards

## Interface

```
public interface JSONSerialisation {
    public JSONObject toJSON();
    public void fromJSON(JSONObject jsonObject);
}
```

## Class

```
public class JSONMessage<T extends JSONSerialisation> {

    private List<T> t;

    public JSONMessage(String json) {
        parseJSONMessage(json);
    }

    public void parseJSONMessage(String json) {
        try {
            this.t = new ArrayList<T>();
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            JSONArray lineItems;
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            this.messageHeader = new MessageHeader(jsonObject.getJSONObject("Header"));

            lineItems = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Data");
            int size = lineItems.length();

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                T t2;
                t2.fromJSON(lineItems.getJSONObject(i));
                t.add(t2);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, add language (I guess it is C#) to tags

Comment: You're not initializing `T t2;`, but using it in the very next line `t2.fromJSON(...);`. This will throw a NPE every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to replace the functionality available from most JSON deserialization libraries. You will notice that most of them require a parametized class, as a solution to the very problem you are facing. It's not the most elegant solution, but it will work. I would drop the generic parameter from the deserialization class, and the stateful variables as well:

```
public class JSONMessage {
    public static <T extends JSONSerialisation> Collection<T> parseJSONMessage(Class<T> clazz, String json) {
        try {
            final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            final JSONArray lineItems = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Data");

            Collection<T> results = new ArrayList<T>(lineItems.size());

            for (final JSONElement elem: lineItems) {
                T result = clazz.newInstance();
                result.fromJSON(elem);
                results.add(result);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public JSONMessage() {
        super();
    }
}
```

The code is obviously missing some error handling, and I made up a bogus `JSONElement` type in the enhanced for loop, but you get the general idea. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 this.t = new ArrayList<JSONSerialisation>();
```

If you eliminate all references to `this` inside that method you can make it static.  Just create a `List` in scope and return it.

I don't see what generics are buying you here.  How likely is it that you're going to have different implementations of that JSON interface?

Comment: Try it and see if it helps.  If not, come back.

Comment: Hello @duffymo, Thanks you for the suggestion.  I plan to use a generic JSON Message class to send back and forth different kind of objects between a Servlet and and Android app. I tried make the class static but this does not solve the issue that I need to create the new object (and instantiate it) before I can add it to the list, and I can not instantiate an object of type JSONSerialisation neither, so I still get an error when I try to add an object to the list `ArrayList<JSONSerialisation>()`

Comment: I think you should simplify your entire approach.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered including the object class in your JSON message?

What about a factory class that implements `fromJSON(JSONObject)` so you can create an instance of the object without first having an instance of the object? The factory could use information about the context within which the JSON was generated to determine the appropriate Java classes. For example, if you've just invoked web-service X you might know the response will either be an piece of data of type Y or an error message of type Z.

In your code above, what if T has a sub-class? How would you distinguish between them?

Ignoring JSON, I thought I'd also answer the part of your question on generics: if you know you have a List, what is T? Java generics work by type-erasure, which means during compilation a lot of the generic type information is erased. However, if you are serializing a POJO into JSON there is good news. The generic type information is retained for classes, fields and methods, so if you had a class like this:

```
class Example extends ArrayList<String> {
    private Set<Integer> someIDs;

    public Map<String,Long> getLongMap() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then it is possible to use reflection to discover that the class implements List where T is String, that the `someIDs` field is an instance of Set where T is Integer and the `getLongMap` method returns an instance of Map where K is String and V is Long. However working your way through the reflection API to get to this information can get quite involved. My code to just identify Collection, Iterator and Enumeration types runs to over 100 lines. I would not recommend trying to do it if you have alternatives.